# Combining two independent pandas dataframes to form matrix

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matrix

I would like to combine two pandas data frames to produce a matrix. The two data frames do not share a common index value and indeed are independent. I instead want to use the two sets of indexes to produce a new data frame using hierarchical indexing which has all of the possible combinations of the two indexes. The columns should take the values from the original data frames.

Here is a simplified version of the two data frames I would like to combine:

```
df1         
    Cat Freq
1.1   A    4
1.2   B    8
1.3   C    2
1.4   A    5

df2
    Cat Freq
2.1   A    4
2.2   C    4
2.3   C    2
2.4   A    7
```

And this is what I want to create:

```
df_merged         
        Cat(1) Freq(1)  Cat(2)   Freq(2)
1.1 2.1  A       4         A       4
    2.2  A       4         C       4
    2.3  A       4         C       2
    2.4  A       4         A       7
1.2 2.1  B       8         A       4
    2.2  B       8         C       4
    2.3  B       8         C       2
 .. ... ....  .......   .......   .......
 .. ... .... ........   .......   .......
```

Ultimately I want want to create a new column with the category letter (originating from either df1 or df2) based on the one with the maximum frequency. With this I will be able to form a matrix. This final step I think will be quite straightforward if I can get the data in the above form.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by both `DataFrames` by `MultiIndex` created [`from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index, df2.index])

df1 = df1.reindex(mux, level=0)
df2 = df2.reindex(mux, level=1)

df = pd.concat([df1.add_suffix('(1)'), df2.add_suffix('(2)')], axis=1)
print (df)
        Cat(1)  Freq(1) Cat(2)  Freq(2)
1.1 2.1      A        4      A        4
    2.2      A        4      C        4
    2.3      A        4      C        2
    2.4      A        4      A        7
1.2 2.1      B        8      A        4
    2.2      B        8      C        4
    2.3      B        8      C        2
    2.4      B        8      A        7
1.3 2.1      C        2      A        4
    2.2      C        2      C        4
    2.3      C        2      C        2
    2.4      C        2      A        7
1.4 2.1      A        5      A        4
    2.2      A        5      C        4
    2.3      A        5      C        2
    2.4      A        5      A        7
```

Or use cross join by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for avoid lost index values:

```
df = (df1.reset_index().assign(A=1)
        .merge(df2.reset_index().assign(A=1), on='A', suffixes=('(1)','(2)'))
        .set_index(['index(1)','index(2)'])
        .drop('A', axis=1)
        .rename_axis((None,None)))
print (df)
        Cat(1)  Freq(1) Cat(2)  Freq(2)
1.1 2.1      A        4      A        4
    2.2      A        4      C        4
    2.3      A        4      C        2
    2.4      A        4      A        7
1.2 2.1      B        8      A        4
    2.2      B        8      C        4
    2.3      B        8      C        2
    2.4      B        8      A        7
1.3 2.1      C        2      A        4
    2.2      C        2      C        4
    2.3      C        2      C        2
    2.4      C        2      A        7
1.4 2.1      A        5      A        4
    2.2      A        5      C        4
    2.3      A        5      C        2
    2.4      A        5      A        7
```